# How to use sessionStorage in sencha?

Tags: javascript, extjs, session-storage

I am trying to have it so that once a user is logged in and they click refresh they will stay on the same page. However right now, when a user is logged in and clicks refresh they are sent back to the login screen. I know session storage is used for while the browser isn't closed, which is what I need. I can't seem to get it to work properly though.

model

```
             Ext.define('MeterReadingsApp.model.Login', {
             extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
              config: {

            fields: [{name: "username", type:'string'}, {name: "password",                                     
               type:'string'}],

                     identifier: 'uuid'

              }
             });
```

store

```
  Ext.define('MeterReadingsApp.store.Login', {
                 extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
                        //requires: ['Ext.data.proxy.SessionStorag'],
                         config: {
                    model: 'MeterReadingsApp.model.Login',

                         //sessionStorage.type: 
                proxy: {
                //use sessionstorage if need to save data for that
              //specific session only
           type: 'sessionstorage',
                  id  : 'Login'
            },
                 autoLoad: false
                   }
           });
        //var Login = Ext.create('MeterReadingsApp.store.Login');
            //Login.load();
```

app.js

```
launch: function() {
    // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
    Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();
    var session=Ext.getStore('Login');
   session.load();
   var  record = session.getAt('userName');
   alert(record);
   if(record != undefined){
       //exits to main menus not login
   }
   else
        Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('MeterReadingsApp.view.Login'));



},
```

controller

```
  loginButton: function(){
// var me = this;

  Ext.Ajax.request({   
           useDefaultXhrHeader:false,
           url: getLogonUrl(),
           method: 'POST',
           headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
           params : {
           "userName": Ext.getCmp('username').getValue(),
           "password": Ext.getCmp('password').getValue()
           },


           success: function (response) {
               Ext.getCmp('failLogin').hide(),

             Ext.getStore('Login').sync();


               Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem({xtype: 'Main'});
               Ext.getStore('Campuses').load();


           },
           failure: function(response) {
              Ext.getCmp('loginform').doSetHeight(250),
              Ext.getCmp('failLogin').show();

           }
        });
     },
```

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the storeId property on the store. You are trying to use the proxy's id to get the store.